# ORA-00904: "MDSYS"."SDO_UTIL"."TO_GML311GEOMETRY": invalid identifier error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I get ORA-00904 error while running simple Query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MDSYS.SDO_UTIL.TO_GML311GEOMETRY(null)) AS Gml311Geometry FROM dual;
```

I tried to use other SDO_UTIL functions (GETVERTICES, SIMPLIFY, TO_WKTGEOMETRY) and they are working just fine. I searched for it in MDSYS packages and I found a proper function to_gml311geometry.

What could be a reason that oracle can't find this function? I use oracle 11g client.

Comment: What Oracle version are we talking about?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Maybe the function is not available in Oracle XE.

Answer (score 0):

As Rene suggested this function is not available in Oracle XE I checked and it does work on full version.